rust compile cassandra-cpp in local
I am trying to run the simple example from cassandra-cpp crate and unable to compile due to linker error (Refer error below). First time encountering a lib with c dependencies and i don't know how to make it compile/run in local.
Error
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: env -u IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET -u TVOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET LC_ALL=
  = note: ld: warning: search path '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' not found
          ld: warning: search path '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' not found
          ld: warning: search path '/usr/local/lib64' not found
          ld: warning: search path '/usr/lib64/' not found
          ld: warning: search path '/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib' not found
          ld: library 'cassandra' not found
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Code - main.rs
use cassandra_cpp::*;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut cluster = Cluster::default();
    cluster.set_contact_points("127.0.0.1").unwrap();
    cluster.set_load_balance_round_robin();
    let session = cluster.connect().await?;

    let result = session
        .execute("SELECT keyspace_name FROM system_schema.keyspaces;")
        .await?;
    println!("{}", result);

    let mut iter = result.iter();
    while let Some(row) = iter.next() {
        let col: String = row.get_by_name("keyspace_name")?;
        println!("ks name = {}", col);
    }

    Ok(())
}

Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "rust_cassandra"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
cassandra-cpp = "3.0.2"
tokio = { version = "1.39.2", features = ["rt", "rt-multi-thread", "macros"] }

Please help me how to compile and run in local using cargo run
EDIT
I installed pre-req datastax drivers as well i mentioned but still no luck and also i tried by installing floki as mentioned by creating a dockerfile.

You have to setup your local environment how to do that depends on what os you're using.

@cafce25 - I tried both ways, driver and floki, but no luck.. I edited the same to mention it which i forget at the start

This: ld: warning: search path '/usr/lib64/' not found is very suspicious. What OS are you using?

Mac M1 Sonoma 14.6.1

Not being a Mac user myself, I'm afraid I can't help you. However other people have had similar issues with other libraries, so maybe one of these answers can be adapted to your use case: 1, 2

Issue is fixed by symlink the openssl. After installing cpp driver as mentioned in library, ensure you install openssl and export the below paths in your terminal or add as env path in bash/zsh config
export LIBRARY_PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/libuv/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH



Note: Tested only in M1 Mac, not sure of other platforms
